# QtConcurrent::map Doesn't accept parameters

Tags: c++, qt, qtconcurrent

I made want to run a function with QtConcurrent::map, but I always get errors...
I have two functions in Mainwindow: `on_listWidget_itemClicked and _fillTreeWithList(QStringList selectedListWidget)`. Function `on_listWidget_itemClicked should use map with _fillTreeWithList.`

**My Code:**

**Header:**

```
QFuture<void> SqlLoadingThread;
void _fillTreeWithList(QStringList);
void on_listWidget_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item);
```

**Cpp:**

```
void MainWindow::on_listWidget_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)
{
    QStringList selectedListWidget;
    QList<QListWidgetItem *> selected=ui->listWidget->selectedItems();
    foreach (QListWidgetItem * item, selected){
        selectedListWidget.append(item->text());
    }
    if(SqlLoadingThread.isRunning()){
        SqlLoadingThread.cancel();
    }
    QList<QStringList> list;
    list.append(selectedListWidget);
    SqlLoadingThread=QtConcurrent::map(&list, &MainWindow::_fillTreeWithList);
}
```

**Error:**

```
  ...mainwindow.cpp:56: Error: no matching function for call to 'map(QList<QStringList>*, void (MainWindow::*)(QStringList))'
 SqlLoadingThread=QtConcurrent::map(&list, &MainWindow::_fillTreeWithList);
                                                                         ^
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: `_fillTreeWithList` may not be a non-static member function.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs Sequence should be taken by reference, not by pointer

```
QFuture<void> QtConcurrent::map ( Sequence & sequence, MapFunction function )
```

Try:

```
SqlLoadingThread=QtConcurrent::map(list, &MainWindow::_fillTreeWithList);
```

Also, you'll need to make your MapFunction take the parameter (QStringList) by reference:

```
void _fillTreeWithList(QStringList&);
```

Comment: Now i get another error:

D:\Programme\Qtneu\5.3\mingw482_32\include\QtConcurrent\qtconcurrentmapkernel.h:71: Fehler: no match for call to '(QtConcurrent::MemberFunctionWrapper1<void, MainWindow, QStringList>) (QStringList&)'
         map(*it);
         ^

I tried out a lot, but nothing want to run :)

Comment: added an addendum above

Comment: Same Error:

no match for call to '(QtConcurrent::MemberFunctionWrapper1<void, MainWindow, QStringList&>) (QStringList&)'
         map(*it);
         ^